# Set Featured Image Based on Custom Field

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have tens of thousands of images. I also have tens of thousands of articles. These were both imported from a custom CMS.

The image filenames are the IDs they had in the old CMS e.g. 12345.jpg

The articles have a custom field called `mainpictureid` which contains the ID of an image.

My question is how to use this custom field to set the featured image of a post. I have the basic loop but not sure what the easiest way is to get the thumbnail ID

```
$children = get_posts('post_type=post');
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $origParentID = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'mainpictureid', true);

    // Somehow get the ID of the image using the ID which will be the filename
    // $thumbID = ???

    set_post_thumbnail( $child->ID, $thumbID); 
}
```

Comment: Is the "mainpictureid" a full URL or just the filename?
Are all the old CMS images been placed in the "wp-content/uploads" folder?

Comment: Just the ID - all uploaded on same day so I know the path. In fact, I've sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$children = get_posts('post_type=event&numberposts=1');
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $origParentID = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'mainpictureid', true);
    $parsed_url  = explode( parse_url( WP_CONTENT_URL, PHP_URL_PATH ), 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/'.$origParentID.'.jpg' );
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE guid RLIKE %s;", $parsed_url[1] ) );
    set_post_thumbnail( $child->ID, $attachment[0]); 
}
```